# Scala type mismatch when adding elements to hashmap

Tags: scala

I am representing a graph's adjacency list in Scala in the variable `a`.

```
        val a = new HashMap[Int, Vector[Tuple2[Int, Int]]] withDefaultValue Vector.empty
        for(i <- 1 to N) {                
            val Array(x, y, r) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
            a(x) += new Tuple2(y, r)
            a(y) += new Tuple2(x, r)
        }
```

I am reading each edge in turn(`x` and `y` are nodes, while `r` is the cost of the edge). After reading it, I am adding it to the adjacency list.

However, when adding the Tuples containing a neighbouring node and a cost to the HashMap I get:

```
Solution.scala:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: String
                a(x) += new Tuple2(y, r)
```

I don't understand why it wants `String`. I haven't specified `String` anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+=` is the operator for concatenating to a `String`.

You would probably want to do something like: `a.update(x, a.getOrElse(x, Vector()) :+ (x, r))`.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you are writing Java code in Scala. It compiles, but amounts to abuse of the language :/

Consider doing  something like this next time:

```
val a = Range(1, N)
   .map { _ => readline.split(" ").map (_.toInt) }
   .flatMap { case Array(x, y, r) => 
       Seq(x -> (y, r), y -> (x, r)) 
   }
   .groupBy(_._1)
   .mapValues { _.map ( _._2) }
```